# How to run the find shell command with the regex option in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, linux, shell

I need to run the Linux find command using the regex option in a ruby script, but it does not seem to work.  All the command does is find files with the extension of rb or erb or js.  I know the command itself is fine because I can run it in the command prompt window.

Here is the find command that I want to run:

```
find . -regex ".*\.\(rb\|erb\|js\)"
```

Here is what my ruby script looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
files = `find . -regex ".*\.\(rb\|erb\|js\)"`
puts files
```

I know I can use the -name option instead of the regex, but it seems like the regex should work.  Also, I was able to get the command `find . -regex ".*\.rb"` to work within my ruby script.  It seems almost like it has a problem with the parenthesis or the pipes?

Any suggestions / help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: If the metacharacters in the script are handled by Ruby, you may try re-escaping like `find . -regex ".*\.(rb|erb|js)"`. Maybe adding `$` or `\z` at the end of the pattern can also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The surmise from [stribizhev's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445130/how-to-run-the-find-shell-command-with-the-regex-option-in-ruby#comment52753745_32445130) is correct: Command literals in backwards quotes are subject to the same escaping and replacement/string interpolation rules as string literals in double quotes (`"`).

String literals in single quotes (`'`) are preserved literally, so the following should work without the need for double-escaping headaches:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
command = 'find . -regex ".*\.\(rb\|erb\|js\)"'
files = `#{command}`
puts files
```

Comment: Apparently, the shell's (`bash` in my case) escaping only modifies sequences of backslashes followed by a special character, and it doesn't consider a dot (`.`) or piple (`|`) inside a double quotes string special. So it does work **for this specific command**, but only because we were lucky. If the pattern contained something that were special in both, regex notation and bash string literals, this would have gone wrong. But then the original command, executed on the shell without ruby, would also have failed.

Comment: Now that depends on the regex dialect. For some dialects, unescaped parentheses are grouping, while escaped ones are literal parentheses, for dialects its the other way around: the escaped parentheses are grouping, while unescaped ones are literal parentheses. It seems (because Jessica's command works as wanted) that `find` uses the latter variation.

Comment: Great :-) Still, do consider @muistooshort's suggestion to use Ruby's `Find` module instead of making it perform command line calls.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has shellescape https://apidock.com/ruby/String/shellescape which lets you explicitely escape arguments to be passed into Unix style shells. Your example could probably be written as

```
`find . -regex #{Shellwords.shellescape ".*\.\(rb\|erb\|js\)"}`
```